# unique solution of an algebraic system

Tags: algebra-precalculus, monotone-functions

Suppose $a,b$ are real numbers satisfying
$$
a = \frac{1}{2} (a+b) +\left(f(a)+f(b)\right)^{3/2},
$$
$$
b = \frac{1}{2} (a+b) -\left(f(a)+f(b)\right)^{3/2}.
$$
Under what conditions on $f$ are $a$ and $b$ uniquely determined from the above.
Suppose for example that $f$ is monotone in a neighborhood of 0, do there exist unique $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Aren't these equations identical?

Comment: they differ by a minus sign

Comment: If you sum first to second you get $a+b=a+b$. If a linear combination of the equations gives us an indetermination then the system has infinte a,b solutioins.